Cant get method to update json file in python
I am making a program to keep track of my barbell lifts. everything is working fine except I want the user.appendLifts() function to update the value of whichever key is being updated in liftsDict. I go through the process by starting the program, then i hit 1 to update lift, then 1 again to update my bench, and when i enter my new bench it takes me back to the previous loop but doesnt update the json file
import json
# data storage
from os.path import exists as file_exists
# checks if files exists


class Trainee():
    def __init__(self):
        # Dictionary of trainee lifts. Lists used to track progress 
        self.liftsDict = {
        'Benchpress weight': [],
        'Press weight': [],
        'Squat weight': [],
        'Deadlift weight': []
        }

    def appendLift(self, lift, weight):
        # Update lifts stored in json file
        with open('user.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            liftsDictJson = data['liftsDict']
            
            lift = lift.title()
            try:
                weight = int(weight)
            except ValueError:
                print(f'{weight} is not a number')
            
            if lift in liftsDictJson:
                liftsDictJson[lift].append(weight)
                print(f'\n{lift} set to {weight}')
        
                with open('user.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    
    def toJSON(self):
        # Save instance data to JSON file
        with open('user.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.__dict__, f, indent=4)
    
    def setup(self):
        # Setup after downloading
        if not file_exists('user.json'):
            print('Setting up new user file...\n'
            'Please fill in the following:\n')              
            for key in self.liftsDict.keys():
                value = int(input(f'{key}: '))
                self.liftsDict[key].append(value)
            user.toJSON()

# Initialize program
user = Trainee()
user.setup()

while True:
    message = """Welcome back!
    Make a selection by entering a number:
    [1]Update working sets
    [2]Exit
    : """
    reply = input(message)
    if reply == '1':
        message = """Which lifts would you like to update?
    [1]Benchpress 3x5
    [2]Press 3x5
    [3]Squat 3x5
    [4]Deadlift 1x5
    [5]Back
    : """
        if reply == '1':
            message = input('Enter new working set for benchpress 3x5: ')
            user.appendLift('Benchpress', message)
    if reply == '2':
        break

I am not sure where to even begin, ive watched videos and scowered the web, asked chatGPT but nothing is really coming close

Why are you writing both self.__dict__ and data to the JSON file?

After the first call to appendLift(), the JSON file will no longer contain the liftsDict key.

you are never changing the data variable that you dump to your file

can you provide your json as well?

you also never update self.liftsDict with the data from the JSON file.
